# args is not defined?

Tags: python, parsing, command-line-arguments

I have this Python script that I'm trying to automate, including parsing arguments:

This is the script:

```
# imported the requests library 
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request 
import os
import argparse

img_urls = pd.read_csv('fotos.csv', skiprows = args["Start"], nrows= args["Rows"] , header = None) 

for i,url in enumerate(img_urls[0]):
    name = "prv_image_{}.jpg".format(i)
    path = 'C:\\Users\\M\\Desktop\\Immages'
    img_path = os.path.join(path,name)
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url,img_path)

# construct the argument parse and parse the arguments

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-S", "--Start", required=True,
                help="Starting Row")
ap.add_argument("-r", "--Rows", required=True,
                help="How Many Rows We Want to take")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
```

The problem is that when I run the above program in the terminal, I get this error:

```
NameError: name 'args' is not defined
```

Any suggestion on how to resolve this problem would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need to define your arguments above where you initially use them

Comment: Future reference as well. Always paste the FULL error traceback. It is much more useful to see the full traceback then just the type of exception that occured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error and [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59718343/args-is-not-defined#comment105587248_59718343) are telling you, `args` is not defined when you use it with:

```py
img_urls = pd.read_csv('fotos.csv', skiprows = args["Start"], nrows= args["Rows"] , header = None)
```

You need to define `args` before it's used.